# Is there a sandbox or test environment available for PHP developer for Cloud services

Tags: php, cloud, sandbox

I am looking for sandbox or test environment where I can learn:

How to deploy PHP applications on Cloud and learn about the basic of Cloud computing.

Like Paypal has sandbox for developers. Is there any such test environment exists for PHP programmers? I would like to know the path I should follow to gain knowledge in cloud readiness based on PHP.

Just to make it clear, I am looking for free service. If free or testing place is not available then very cheaper service is also good to know for developers point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest trying Amazon Web Services as from some time they offer free usage tier for users http://aws.amazon.com/free/

Comment: Really a useful link. Now looking for sample usage of Amazon Web services. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We offer a free tier. You can have multiple apps and deployments for free within certain limits (max 1 box per hour and the limits of the free add-on options you may choose).

Feel free to try it at http://cloudcontrol.com and if you have any questions I'm around and happy to answer them.